# Is there any possible way to give an all the services (windows and 3rd party) access to the non admin users?

Tags: windows, user-management, user-permissions

I am planning to give all the services start /stop access to the users(non-admin) I don't want to give the administrator group access to them.

I have a couple of windows servers running with a couple of third-party services, So just I want to give those services access to my team.

I have tried to create a group policy, but I am not able to give access to all the services, I can only able to give specific windows services only.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/

What I would do is create a GPP schedule task that runs daily.

- Create a group for your users
- create a ps script that will loop through all services and check if the service has the group assigned to it.

  - if not assign the rights the to group as outlined in this article.
- use gpp to run that ps script via a scheduled task as system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerShell Just Enough Administration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-5.1) (JEA). It requires some setup but you can define which services a normal user can start/stop.

This will only work if the users are using PowerShell to start/stop services. It doesn't work if they want to use the GUI.